# After losing connection to a server, I am unable to connect to it again

Tags: networking, dns, connection

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but let's hope so!

I have had this issue for a while, but it has usually just resolved itself over time, but now it has lasted for quite a bit of time so I'm just wondering if there might be a fix I can try to get this out of the way.

So I have a server on a specific IP. I connect to this server trough SSH, web, and trough a Mumble (VOIP) connection.

Now, if I lose my internet connection, or if the server loses it's internet connection, I am not able to connect back to server again, even though everyone else can and even though I can connect to everything else.

Tracert:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

The solutions tried so far:

- Obtaining new IP from the router itself
- Restarting computer
- Changing DNS-server on client PC (to e.g. google-dns)
- ipconfig/flushdns -> /release -> /renew
- Disabling every network adapter except the one needed for internet

Now the funny part is that if I run a VirtualBox client, I can connect to the server just fine, which leads me to think that this might a server issue. But like it probably seems to you by now, I have no idea how to fix this, really.

I have not tried doing anything from the server regarding this issue at the moment, since the problem only seems to be towards my PC I didn't want to restart/disconnect the server for everyone using it just for my problem.

As I am writing this several paragraphs later, I can now connect to the server again, but like I said previously, I would like some input from you guys if you have some, to find a quicker solution than "just wait" next time this happens.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would need to dig deeper but a possible solution for you would be, assuming the server IP doesn't change, just hardcode the IP in your host file.  I've had a similar issue myself and that worked.  Can't be sure why as pinging the IP didn't work for me therefore a host entry shouldn't do anything, but I can assure you it helped.

Josh

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've added it to hosts now. Will mark this as answer if it works next time this happens :)